# How to link jni/ndk with precompiled object file

Tags: java, android, c, makefile, interop

I need to link my application with a precompiled object file but don't know how to specify it in the makefile.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_MODULE    := mymp3gain
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

this is the native functionality that would be called from android app

```
#include <jni.h>

#include "mp3gain-1_5_2_r2-src/mp3gain.h"

void Java_com_example_rockboost_MainActivity_gain()


{
    changeGain("Kalimba.mp3", 5, 5);
};
```

The library i want to link is in a subfolder of jni ( jni/mp3gain-1_5_2_r2-src/mp3gain.o

So how do I link it using android native call makefiles?